# I have three QuerySets from one table. 'asiento' and create lista1, lista2 and lista3

Tags: python, django, sorting

```
lista1 = asiento.objects.all().annotate(grupo= Substr("cuenta__codigo",1,1)).values('grupo').annotate(sum_debe=Sum("debe"),sum_haber=Sum("haber"))
lista2 = asiento.objects.all().annotate(grupo = Substr("cuenta__codigo",1,3)).values('grupo').annotate(sum_debe=Sum("debe"),sum_haber=Sum("haber"))
lista3 = asiento.objects.all().annotate(grupo = Substr("cuenta__codigo",1,6)).values('grupo').annotate(sum_debe=Sum("debe"),sum_haber=Sum("haber"))
```

Chain then three QuerySets:

```
listan = chain(lista1,lista2,lista3)
```

The result of the chain in the variable listan is:

```
{'grupo': '1', 'sum_debe': Decimal('251.680000000000'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('0')}

{'grupo': '2', 'sum_debe': Decimal('0'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('251.680000000000')}

{'grupo': '1.0', 'sum_debe': Decimal('194.120000000000'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('0')}

{'grupo': '1.2', 'sum_debe': Decimal('37.5600000000000'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('0')}

{'grupo': '1.3', 'sum_debe': Decimal('20'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('0')}

{'grupo': '2.1', 'sum_debe': Decimal('0'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('143.450000000000')}

{'grupo': '2.3', 'sum_debe': Decimal('0'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('22.5600000000000')}

{'grupo': '2.4', 'sum_debe': Decimal('0'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('85.6700000000000')}

{'grupo': '1.0.80', 'sum_debe': Decimal('128.450000000000'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('0')}

{'grupo': '1.0.90', 'sum_debe': Decimal('65.6700000000000'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('0')}

{'grupo': '1.2.00', 'sum_debe': Decimal('27.5600000000000'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('0')}

{'grupo': '1.2.40', 'sum_debe': Decimal('10'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('0')}

{'grupo': '1.3.20', 'sum_debe': Decimal('20'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('0')}

{'grupo': '2.1.00', 'sum_debe': Decimal('0'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('123.450000000000')}

{'grupo': '2.1.50', 'sum_debe': Decimal('0'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('20')}

{'grupo': '2.3.70', 'sum_debe': Decimal('0'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('22.5600000000000')}

{'grupo': '2.4.00', 'sum_debe': Decimal('0'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('45.6700000000000')}

{'grupo': '2.4.45', 'sum_debe': Decimal('0'), 'sum_haber': Decimal('40')}
```

I need to order by a new field 'grupo' created in every query sets with annotate. When I sort (listan) with the chain result using the new 'grupo' field.

```
listan = sorted(chain(lista1,lista2,lista3),key=attrgetter('grupo'))
```

I receive the error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'grupo'
```

Comment: Because you need `itemetter` and not `attrgetter` to get items instead of attributes?..

Answer (score 0):

`attrgetter` isn't meant for dicts, use `itemgetter` or a `lambda` function.

Try this

```
from operator import itemgetter
listan = sorted(chain(lista1,lista2,lista3),key=itemgetter('grupo'))
```

or

```
listan = sorted(chain(lista1,lista2,lista3),key=lambda d: d['grupo'])
```